# background-color on dropdown menu and submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need `submenu` once hovered - displayed at the bottom of its parent `menu-device__item` and move down next `li`s.

So on `:hover` I increase `height` of the `menu-device__item`.
And while `:animated` its background (full height) is painted red of course.

How do I fix this?
I suppose I should change `height` of its `submenu` but I cannot do it right.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var menu = $('.menu-device__menu');

  $('.menu__button').click(
    function() {
      $(this).find(menu).slideToggle('slow');
   });

  
  $('.menu-device__item').hover(
    function(){
      var n = $(this).find('.submenu__item').length;

      if (n > 0) {
        $(this).height((n + 1)  * 35);
      } else ( $(this).height(35) );

      $(this).find('.submenu').slideDown('slow');
    },

    function(){
      $(this).height(35);
      $(this).find('.submenu').slideUp('fast');
    });

})
```

```css
.menu-device {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  z-index: 1000;
}

.menu-device .menu__button {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 37px;
  width: 105px;
  height: 58px;
  float: right;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu {
  width: 282px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 95px;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: -3px 0 10px #ababab inset;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item {
  background-image: url("../../img/menu_icon.png");
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 252px;
  height: 35px;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item .menu__link {
  color: #494949;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item .submenu {
  background-color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 35px;
  display: none;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item .submenu .submenu__item {
  line-height: 35px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 252px;
  height: 35px;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item .submenu .submenu__item .submenu__link {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #494949;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item .submenu .submenu__item:hover {
  background-color: #a90027;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item .submenu .submenu__item:hover .submenu__link {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item:nth-child(1),
.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item:nth-child(3),
.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item:nth-child(6) {
  background-image: none;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item:hover {
  background-color: #a90027;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item:hover .menu__link {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-device .menu__logo {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 135px;
  margin-left: 91px;
  z-index: 2000;
}

.menu-device .menu__logo img {
  margin-top: -20px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>    

<nav class="menu-device">

      <div class="menu__button">
        <a class="menu__pic" href="#"><img src="img/responsive_nav.png" alt="expand"></a>
        <ul class="menu-device__menu">
          <li class="menu-device__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Menu Item</a></li>

          <li class="menu-device__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Menu Item</a>
          
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="menu-device__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Menu Item</a></li>



          <li class="menu-device__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Menu Item</a>    
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="menu-device__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Menu Item</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="menu-device__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </nav>
```

http://codepen.io/ArkadiyS/pen/JKRKzL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring the `background-color` hover rule to the nested `a` element instead.

**Removed**

```
/*.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item:hover {
  background-color: #a90027;
} Don't need this rule declared on the list element */
```

**Adjusted**

```
.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item:hover .menu__link {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #a90027; /* Declare background-color hither! */
}
```

**Added**

```
.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item > a {
    display: block;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item .submenu a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var menu = $('.menu-device__menu');

  $('.menu__button').click(
    function() {
      $(this).find(menu).slideToggle('slow');
   });

  
  $('.menu-device__item').hover(
    function(){
      var n = $(this).find('.submenu__item').length;

      if (n > 0) {
        $(this).height((n + 1)  * 35);
      } else ( $(this).height(35) );

      $(this).find('.submenu').slideDown('slow');
    },

    function(){
      $(this).height(35);
      $(this).find('.submenu').slideUp('fast');
    });

})
```

```css
.menu-device {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  z-index: 1000;
}

.menu-device .menu__button {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 37px;
  width: 105px;
  height: 58px;
  float: right;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu {
  width: 282px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 95px;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: -3px 0 10px #ababab inset;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item {
  background-image: url("../../img/menu_icon.png");
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 252px;
  height: 35px;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item .menu__link {
  color: #494949;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item .submenu {
  background-color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 35px;
  display: none;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item .submenu .submenu__item {
  line-height: 35px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 252px;
  height: 35px;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item .submenu .submenu__item .submenu__link {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #494949;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item .submenu .submenu__item:hover {
  background-color: #a90027;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item .submenu .submenu__item:hover .submenu__link {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item:nth-child(1),
.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item:nth-child(3),
.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item:nth-child(6) {
  background-image: none;
}

/*.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item:hover {
  background-color: #a90027;
} Don't need this rule declared on the list element */

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item:hover .menu__link {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #a90027; /* Declare background-color hither! */
}

.menu-device .menu__logo {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 135px;
  margin-left: 91px;
  z-index: 2000;
}

.menu-device .menu__logo img {
  margin-top: -20px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* Added Rules */

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item > a {
    display: block;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.menu-device .menu-device__menu .menu-device__item .submenu a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>    

<nav class="menu-device">

      <div class="menu__button">
        <a class="menu__pic" href="#"><img src="img/responsive_nav.png" alt="expand"></a>
        <ul class="menu-device__menu">
          <li class="menu-device__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Menu Item</a></li>

          <li class="menu-device__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Menu Item</a>
          
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="menu-device__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Menu Item</a></li>



          <li class="menu-device__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Menu Item</a>    
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="menu-device__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Menu Item</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li class="submenu__item"><a href="" class="submenu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="menu-device__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </nav>
```

Comment: thanks, it's better now, but I get this new problem: http://i.imgur.com/vZl9lRs.jpg -- the issue is that white sector because of paddig-right. Is it possible to make whole line red?

Comment: I don't see that issue in the code snippet I've embedded into my answer. Have another look at your styles, looks like the `background-color` is still being applied to the `li` item, or that the `padding-right` hasn't been removed from the `li`, the padding should be applied to the `a` element instead.